# IONIC3 - How to add rxjs debounceTime and distinctUntilChanged to ion-auto-complete in the getResult method

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Iam working on a project where the developper who worked on befor me used ionic-auto-complete theird party library.
Iam wondering how to use debounce and distuncUntilChanged in the AutocompleteService.
Iam stuck on it, if anyone can help me please. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it could be helpful to anyone, I found that for de debounce, you could add it in the property options[], it uses the debounce property of ion searchbar. But for distuncUntilChanged, I think it should be an update to the component from his creator.